# Managing Dependencies of libraries in Android

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

I have 5 Android Projects, they all have similar dependencies like Dagger, retrofit , Rx and so on.
 Is there a standard way i can manage versions of all the dependencies, in a way where all the projects share the same version of a particular library.

Sample:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger_version}"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitLibVersion}"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitLibVersion}"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:${retrofitLibVersion}"
```

In the above sample `dagger_version` and `retrofitLibVersion` is something i want do define at one place and consume it in all projects.

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to define these as `ext` in your root project *build.gradle*:

```
ext {
    dagger_version = '2.19'
    retrofitLibVersion = '2.4.0 '
}
```

This could also be achieved by loading a remote or local *Gradle* file and `apply` it to the root project or to every subproject as needed:

```
apply from: 'versions.gradle'
```

Comment: all of my projects are independent projects. I just want to maintain consistency among all the projects.

Comment: How to host a remote gradle file?